# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, isolatedstorage

I have been trying to open a file on c: drive using Isolated Storage, I tried different ways but they all give the same error, here's the code;

```
IsolatedStorageFile ifs = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
Stream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("avi.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, ifs);
```

I even tried:

1)

```
Stream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(@"avi.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, ifs);
```

2)

```
Stream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(@"files/avi.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, ifs);
```

3)

```
Stream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("files/avi.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, ifs);
```

how can I open the file without using a Dialog box.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain the error you are seeing since I would gave expected to see file not found error.

It sounds to me that you are attempting to use isolated storage to access a file in the clients file system.

You need to be running an OOB with elevated trust.  Then you can use System.IO.File to open a file and even then you are restricted to the MyDocuments area for the current user.

Outside of that you do need to show the user a dialog.

Comment: Hi Anthony, the error was Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream, but I'll try and put the file on Documents. Do I need to specify the file path, if so how?

Comment: @Sandile:  My answer wasn't clear enough.  You __cannot__ use the IsolatedStorage classes to access files in the normal file system on the client machine.  Thats what the "Isolated" bit means.  Isolated storage provides a form of a file system which is entirely owned by and can only be used by the specific application or Site.  To access normal files on the client machine you either need to ask the user to select one via the dialog __OR__ have your app installed as a Trusted OOB and even then you can only access files in the users MyDocuments area.